# Ie7 random float offset

Tags: html, css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I'm getting the strange ie7 float bug.
Where on my div I'm getting offset left 20px;

I've setup a jsfiddle bellow that replicates the error I'm experiencing.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/NR7BT/1/)

### html code

```
<div class="input-area short">
   <label for="phone">Phone</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="phone" class="fillout">
</div>

<div class="input-area short">
   <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="dob" class="fillout">
</div>
```

## css code

```
.input-area{
   margin-top:15px;
}
.input-area.short{
   float:left;
   margin-right:8px;
}
.sweepstake-competition label {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 10px;
}
.fillout {
   background-color: #FAFBFB;
   border: 1px solid #999999;
   border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
   height: 22px;
   width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: I get the same result in ie7 and FF10...

Comment: Yeah me too. Just delete `margin-left: 20px` in `.sweepstake-competition form`. http://jsfiddle.net/NR7BT/2/

Comment: Thanks guy, changed the margin-left to padding-left. Have you use it for styling issues. Unsure on how the margining could only effect the bottom two div's that were floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used padding instead of margins.
Margins were clashing with floats.